# How to install jenkins remotely on another server

Tags: jenkins, remote-server

How to install jenkins remotely on another server. I want to run a script on my server that will install jenkins on another server.

Comment: Where is the another server? You can write a script which has commands of installation of Jenkins and trigger it on another server.

Comment: Both the servers are on cloud. Both are linux machines.

Comment: So for this you need to write a bash script in which you do SSH into the other server and execute installation commands of Jenkins.

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: Yes it's resolved.